# Kerberos cross realm authentication for kadmin

Tags: kerberos, mitkerberos

We have set up cross realm authentication using MIT Kerberos, it's quite straightforward if you adhere to the docs. But we are missing one feature: We'd like to be able to authenticate to the kadmind of some "sub"-realms using principals in an "administrative" realm. Is this even possible?